# Move counter displays result one less than expected

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a memory game and I implemented a move counter to calculate the number of tries(moves) to finish the game. But the result I get is one less than expected. (i.e., if the expected is 9 , i get 8 ). Help me out .

```
var matches = 0;
var moves = 0;
var counter = document.querySelector(".moves");
```

the function to count the moves:

```
function moveCounter(){
++moves;
//counter.innerHTML = moves;
}
```

the count is made when the second click is made on the memory game and it is counted as first move.

```
for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
{
buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
var turnable = e.target.dataset.turnable;


//first click
if (!wait && lastKnownButtonId == undefined && lastKnownButtonNumber == undefined && turnable == 'true') {
  e.target.dataset.turnable = 'false';

  e.target.innerHTML = getgImage(event.target.dataset.number);
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';

  lastKnownButtonId = e.target.id;
  lastKnownButtonNumber = e.target.dataset.number;
 }

//second click
else if (!wait && lastKnownButtonId != undefined && lastKnownButtonNumber != undefined && turnable == 'true' && e.target.id != lastKnownButtonId) {
  e.target.dataset.turnable = 'false';

  e.target.innerHTML = getgImage(event.target.dataset.number);




  //match
  if (e.target.dataset.number == lastKnownButtonNumber) {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#00FF7F';
    document.getElementById(lastKnownButtonId).style.backgroundColor = '#00FF7F';

    lastKnownButtonId = undefined;
    lastKnownButtonNumber = undefined;

    matches++;


    if (matches == 8) {

    showWinScreen();

    document.getElementById("finalMove").innerHTML = moves;


    }

  }

  //no match
  else {
    document.getElementById(lastKnownButtonId).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    wait = true;

    setTimeout(() => {
      e.target.dataset.turnable = 'true';
      e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'white'
      e.target.innerHTML = getgImage(0);


      var tempLastClickedButton = document.getElementById(lastKnownButtonId);

      tempLastClickedButton.dataset.turnable = 'true';
      tempLastClickedButton.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
      tempLastClickedButton.innerHTML = getgImage(0);

      lastKnownButtonId = undefined;
      lastKnownButtonNumber = undefined;
      wait = false;
    }, 1000);


  }
  moveCounter();
}

});
}
```

when the game finishes, the moves should be displayed

```
if (matches == 8) {

    showWinScreen();

    document.getElementById("finalMove").innerHTML = moves;
    }
```

Suppose " I expect the output of moves= 12, but i get the output = 11"

Comment: This appears to be a "0 based index" thing. If it's always 1 less that you're expecting, have you tried this? `document.getElementById("finalMove").innerHTML = moves + 1;`

Comment: @MarkHillard i tried with document.getElementById("finalMove").innerHTML = moves + 1; but still no changes, it gives the output one less than expected

Comment: How can both `moves` and `moves + 1` be one less than expected??

Comment: @Nickolay thats the problem i asked here, whatever changes i make to the move the answer less one than expected.